# Print html with images (every image on separate page)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, image, printing

I have an HTML with images:

```
<img id="1" .../>
<img id="2" .../>
<img id="3" .../>
<img id="4" .../>
```

While printing, I want every image to be on a separate page (according to the print size).

Now I get the images cut off in the middle.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I have 81 images and I get 78 print pages (I see the pages cut in the middle).

Comment: I tried: <style>
@media print
{
img {page-break-after:always;}
}
</style>

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media print {
                p.pageBreak {page-break-after: always;}
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p class="pageBreak">
        <img id="1" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    </p>
    <p class="pageBreak">
        <img id="2" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    </p>
    <p class="pageBreak">
        <img id="3" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    </p>
    <p class="">
        <img id="4" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```